# What form of analysis should be used for loss given default estimates?

Tags: r, time-series, classification, credit-scoring

I am working on BASEL II IRB models and we have to estimate loss based on historic defaults.

There are different outcomes/scenarios we have identified that a default can encounter that will affect the LGD like CURE, FORCED SALE, LOSS, PARTIAL CURE.  We have the data needed to be able to allow the classification to happen, but I am unsure of what form of analysis is best suited to process this data and produce the necessary segmentations and subsequent estimates of loss for each one.

We have data currently in a format with one row per month per default for every month including and since the account first defaulted.  A number of scenarios involve activity over a number of months for a defaulted account.

I am unsure what form of analysis I shoud be performing.  I considered classification trees but as a criteria can span multiple months (in rows) I don't think this would work and I also considered time series analysis but this is a new area for me and I'm not sure whether it can pull out events.

What form of analysis should I be using and are there any specific resources for it in R that you think would be helpful?

**UPDATE**

I have reduced the dataset to a series of 6 month snapshots and classifed each account at each position such that I have a dataset like

`ID,Age,LGDstatus,LTV,BTV,[OTHER CHARACTERISTICS],Bal,BalChangeSinceInception`

where a predictive model needs to be built such that we can predict how much BalChangeSinceInception is expected for each LGDstatus at each point, and the likelihood that an account will go to the various LGDstatus.

Simplisticly then I could build a prediction which says...
An account has gone into default, based on these x factors, by month Y we expect a loss of z% based on an a% probability of experiencing LOSS and a b% probability of experiencing a CURE

However, that may be the wrong approach and direction would be invaluable.

Comment: I don't have a first hand experience doing this, but based on the description of the problem, it seems, you could use longitudinal logit models.